# How to trigger codemirror search from my custom search dialog box

Tags: search, dialog, codemirror

I am using CodeMirror in anguar 9. I can trigger the search on the click of a button and the code mirror's search dialog opens..

This is what I do
const editor = this.codeEditor.codeMirror;
editor.execCommand("find");

but I want to put in my own dialog box instead of code mirror's. How do I go about it?